# Sort data in array

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, core-data

I have an array coming from Core Data that I want to sort, using an `orderNum` field that I added to the database (`Scene` entity).

I make the following request to get data:

```
NSArray *scenes;

NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Scenes" inManagedObjectContext:context];

[fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
NSError *error;

scenes = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
return scenes;
```

How do I go about sorting the data returned in `scenes` by `orderNum`?

Comment: Why you don't sort while calling the Database?

Comment: It's a pre-built app that I am maintaining. I can't figure out where the query for this table in the database is being called. Like I would have modified the SQL to sort by the orderNum. Any idea, how I can trace it in the program?

Comment: @user3473089 If you are now maintaining this code, it appears that a top priority would be reading the [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use an `NSSortDescriptor` with `orderNum` as the `key` and apply that sort descriptor to your `fetchRequest`.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"orderNum" ascending:YES];
[fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[ sort ]];
```

Comment: Yes, this is the right approach - and it's worth noting that having SQL engine do the sort as part of the fetch will be WAY faster and more efficient than retrieving the data and then sorting it in code. Especially if you're sorting on a column that has an index in SQL-land...

Comment: Do you know how I can access the SQL engine?

Comment: You have no direct access to SQL through Core Data. Calling `executeFetchRequest:` converts the fetch request to SQL and runs it (privately).

Answer (score 0):

The best approach is to retrieve the data from the Database sorted. Check @Wain answer for that.

However it is possible to sort the data into an `NSArray` of dictionaries, too:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sceneDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"orderNum" ascending:YES];
NSArray * sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject: sceneDescriptor];
NSArray *sortedArray = [scene sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

NSLog(@"sortedArray = %@", sortedArray);
```